# Problem with NIntegrate a solution of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm having trouble making a function that uses the result of `NDSolve`:

```
c=1/4;
soln = NDSolve[{c^2*D[u[x, t], x, x] == D[u[x, t], t, t], 
         u[x, 0] == UnitTriangle[2*x - 1], 
         Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, u[0, t] == 0, 
         u[1, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 4/c}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
             "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}]

energy[(t_)?NumericQ] := 
     (1/2)*NIntegrate[Evaluate[
           D[u[x, t]^2, t] + c^2*D[u[x, t]^2, x] /. 
               First[soln]], {x, 0, 1}, 
         MaxRecursion -> 10, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
```

Evaluating `energy[0.5]` gives the error: `` General::ivar: 0.5` is not a valid variable. ``

Inspecting the definition with `??energy` shows `Evaluate` didn't work.

After changing the definition to:

```
expr = D[u[x, t]^2, t] + c^2*D[u[x, t]^2, x] /. First[soln];
energy[(t_)?NumericQ] := (1/2)*NIntegrate[Evaluate[expr], 
         {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
         Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
```

using `energy[t]` inside `Table` and `Plot` work, but `energy[0.5]` gives a `NIntegrate::inumri` error with `NIntegrate` left unevaluated and containing exactly what `expr` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't take derivative w.r.t. a number. You were passing `t` as number, then doing `D[...,t]`

Try the following. It is also easier to use `NDSolveValue`

```
ClearAll[u, x, t]
c = 1/4;
soln = NDSolveValue[{c^2*D[u[x, t], x, x] == D[u[x, t], t, t], 
    u[x, 0] == UnitTriangle[2*x - 1], Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, 
    u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 4/c}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}];
energy[t0_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{t}, (1/2)*
   NIntegrate[
    D[soln[x, t]^2, t] + c^2*D[soln[x, t]^2, x] /. t -> t0, {x, 0, 1},
     MaxRecursion -> 10, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
  ]
```

And now

```
energy[0.5]

(*-0.093744*)
```

Comment: So what's going on with Evaluate? Isn't it supposed to evaluate an expression at the time of definition, regardless of the := ? And why does it work in Table and Plot? That's the behavior clearly given in the documentation on Evaluate under: "Force evaluation of the right-hand side of a delayed definition".